# Google GIS migration credential expires in an hour | Token Renewal

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin, refresh-token, google-identity

After migrating to GIS sign-in, I am getting an issue that the given jwt token is expired in 1 hour and I cannot find any other way to renew it. It's annoying the user to logout and login again.

When try to generate from the other way by initiating the new token using `requestAccessToken` method. I'm getting an `access_token` and not a jwt token that can be used only for authorization purpose like reading data from the Google API's, not useful in this case.

In this case, how do we get a **refresh token**?

Implemented by using this below article:

Frontend: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration

Backend: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token

For the backend, we are using **Python**, and verifying the token with that same method `verify_oauth2_token`.

Is anyone had the same issue and found any solutions?

Comment: Its JavaScript your going to have to request authorization from the user again.  Access tokens are only valid for an hour.   Refresh tokens only work with server sided languages.

Comment: @DaImTo How the flow should be, here we get a jwt token after GIS migration in frontend which we validate with `verify_oauth2_token` method. It works fine for 1 hour. After that, generated `access_token` and sent for backend validation, but it fails in the same method.

Comment: Again access tokens expire after an hour your going to have to request authorization of the user again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the access token after the 1 hour limit, and don't want to have to prompt the user again each time, you will need to use the GIS Code flow instead ([following this doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model)), or a Server side implementation (see [these pages of Google's doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow)).

This Code flow is a bit more complicated (not a lot) and gives you an Authentication code which you can exchange for an Access + Refresh token. With the Refresh token, you will be able to refresh the Access token without having to prompt the user for consent again. You will also be able to revoke these codes at any time.